# Django server cache select statement in Postgres DB

Tags: django, postgresql, caching, django-models

I have a select Django statement like this:

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from mobileapp.models import *
import math
from functools import partial
from django.utils import timezone
from mobileapp.decorators import logging__time 


date=timezone.now()
first = date.replace(day=1)
last_month = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
subsidiaries = Subsidiary.objects.select_related('frequency').select_related('last_call').filter(user=user).annotate(number_of_calls=Count('calls', filter=Q(calls__start__gte=last_month, calls__start__date__lte=date)))
```

Even though today date is 6.30. the query in the logs look like this:

```
SELECT 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."id",
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."subsidiary_ref", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."name", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."address", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."city", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."coordinates_x", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."coordinates_y", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."phone_number", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."frequency_id", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."channel", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."subchannel", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."user_id", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."day_planned", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."customer_id", 
 "mobileapp_subsidiary"."last_call_id", 
 COUNT("mobileapp_calls"."id") FILTER (
 WHERE (("mobileapp_calls"."start" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Ljubljana')::date <= '2020-06-11'::date AND "mobileapp_calls"."start" >= '2020-05-31T08:01:06.244114+00:00'::timestamptz)) AS "number_of_calls", "mobileapp_frequency"."name", "mobileapp_frequency"."calls_per_month", T5."id", T5."start", T5."end", T5."notes", T5."type", T5."user_id", T5."subsidiary_id", T5."order_id" FROM "mobileapp_subsidiary" LEFT OUTER JOIN "mobileapp_calls" ON ("mobileapp_subsidiary"."id" = "mobileapp_calls"."subsidiary_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "mobileapp_frequency" ON ("mobileapp_subsidiary"."frequency_id" = "mobileapp_frequency"."name") LEFT OUTER JOIN "mobileapp_calls" T5 ON ("mobileapp_subsidiary"."last_call_id" = T5."id") WHERE "mobileapp_subsidiary"."user_id" = 2 GROUP BY "mobileapp_subsidiary"."id", "mobileapp_frequency"."name", T5."id"; args=(datetime.date(2020, 6, 11), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 31, 8, 1, 6, 244114, tzinfo=<UTC>), 2);
```

I check the later logs and it is always query for 6.11 (even for previous days).

It looks like the query is cached somehow and called the same query every time, even that date is changed...

if I use Django-extensions shell and I run the function from there, it queries the right result.

Any idea?

### EDIT:

Model for subsidiary looks like this:

```
class Subsidiary(models.Model):

    subsidiary_ref = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=80)
    address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    coordinates_x = models.DecimalField(null=True, decimal_places=5, max_digits=9)
    coordinates_y = models.DecimalField(null=True, decimal_places=5, max_digits=9)
    phone_number = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    frequency = models.ForeignKey(Frequency, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, db_index=True)
    channel = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    subchannel = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='subsidiaries', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, db_index=True)
    day_planned = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subsidiaries')

    last_call = models.ForeignKey('Calls', related_name="subsidiary_reference", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True,blank=True, db_index=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your model?

Comment: is the date correct on the server this code is running on?

Comment: Yes, a date should be correct on the server. If I run python shell and put date now, I get the correct date.

Comment: @IainShelvington,  I add the model in question.

Comment: Have you tried logging/printing `last_month`?

Comment: Yes, this is correct for the date. As you can see from the select statement, today date is wrong.